# How to inset a customer location through graph

Tags: acumatica

Hello I am banging my head against the wall trying find the correct way to insert a customer location using a graph.  I am currently using the PX.Objects.CR.CustomerLocationMaint graph.  But when I insert or set current location it is always null.

Here is my code

```
          private PX.Objects.CR.Location UpdateCustomerLocation(PX.Objects.AR.Customer cust, ListingRead currentListing, ListingContactRelnListing contact)
    {

        PX.Objects.AR.CustomerLocationMaint g = new PX.Objects.AR.CustomerLocationMaint();

        g.Clear(PXClearOption.ClearAll);

        g.BusinessAccount.Current = cust;

        PX.Objects.CR.Location loc = new PX.Objects.CR.Location();

        loc.BAccountID = cust.BAccountID;
        loc.LocationCD = "RL" + contact.contact.id;
        loc.Descr = currentListing.property.system_search_key;
        loc.DefContactID = cust.DefContactID;

        loc.IsActive = true;
        loc.LocType = "CU";

        g.Location.Current = loc;
        loc = g.Location.Insert(loc);

        PX.Objects.CR.Address addr = new PX.Objects.CR.Address();

        addr.BAccountID = cust.BAccountID;
        addr.AddressType = "BS";
        addr.CountryID = "NZ";
        addr.AddressLine1 = currentListing.property.adr_street_number + " " + currentListing.property.adr_street_name;
        addr.AddressLine2 = currentListing.property.adr_suburb_or_town;
        addr.AddressLine3 = currentListing.property.adr_state_or_region;

        addr = g.Address.Insert(addr);

        loc.DefAddressID = addr.AddressID;
        g.Location.Update(loc);

        g.Actions.PressSave();

        return loc;
    }
```

Comment: you mean that after g.Address.Insert(addr); addr is null ?

Comment: After g.Location.Insert(loc) loc is null.  I wonder if I should be using the CustomerMaint graph instead?

Comment: try  loc = g.Location.Insert(loc); just after setting the BAccountID. Then set the other values and update the record to cache.